# python code executed in class without it being instantiated

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

why does running the code below yields "Hello"?

```
class MyClass(object):
    print('Hello')

    def __init__(self):
        print('Hi')
```

In other words, why does python runs the code inside the class without it being instantiated? 
PS: I know that shouldn't be done, just trying to understand why it happens.